# The windows registry was not in the expected state. Please run the Illustrator installer

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, adobe-illustrator

I've searched through the internet in order to solve this problem in adobe illustrator CS3 unfortunately I am still encountering it.

I've already

1. Restarted my computer
2. Reinstalled the application

During my research most of the users are encountering this problem using Windows Vista, I am using windows 8.1.

Although I can open the Adobe Illustrator it outputs text instead of vector.

Comment: Only thing i can tell you is unistalling does not always clear the registry of all the stuff put in there. Adobe has supplied (at times) a "cleaner" application for (usually) the whole suite of programs so a clean(er) install can occur.  The version CS3 is a earlier version of the adobe stuff than the win 8.1 , it could be some more secured or higher permission registry lockdown by the newer OS adds to the issues of the registry cruff remaining, and updating registry entries.  See if you can find a cleaner and run it as admin.  Plus other things that have changed in the OS since.

Comment: @Psycogeek isn't this an answer Sir? :) Thanks! I'll try that.

Comment: It is a  guess, and one possible method. If you solution the problem for real, please fully outline what you did in a self answer, to help others.